# Filter rows based on date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a set of data that resembles this format:

```
id,timestamp,pid
[(1231, '2015-08-31 15:21:15', 1546),
 (3451, '2015-09-01 15:21:15', 4984),
 (4561, '2015-09-01 15:21:15', 6464),
 (5671, '2015-09-02 15:21:15', 5484)]
```

I'm trying to extract the rows that contain the date "2015-09-01". I thought about applying a map, but it works on the row as a whole if I understood it correctly.

So I tried another alternative by attempting

```
datetime.strptime(df.timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

but got this:

```
TypeError: must be str, not method
```

Ultimately I thought of extracting the rows that match this condition:

```
datetime.strptime("2015-08-30 23:59:59", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") > 
               datetime.strptime(df.timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") >
               datetime.strptime("2015-09-02 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

**My question**

What would be a more proper way to implement that method, or is there another alternative?

Comment: Is the data in trhe format `str`, `str,str,str`, or something else?

Comment: I'm doing a simple read_csv, so whatever is being done by pandas. They should all be in string format.

Comment: you can parse the csv doing something like `df = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=[1])` then you can filter `df[df['timestamp'] == '2015--09-01']`

Comment: @EdChum Thank you. I did `df[df['timestamp'] >= '2015-09-01']` and first row was removed. Is it possible to include  `'2015-09-02' >=` as well in one line?

Comment: `df[(df['timestamp'] == '2015-09-01') & (df['info'] >= '2015-09-01')]` should work]

Comment: `df[(df['timestamp'] >= '2015-09-01') & (df['timestamp'] <= '2015-09-02')]` that was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `filter`. Since all dates are formatted using `-` this works fine:

```
filter(lambda x: '2015-09-01' in x[1], the_list)
```

Which results in:

```
[(3451, '2015-09-01 15:21:15', 4984), (4561, '2015-09-01 15:21:15', 6464)]
```

You can also do stuff like:

```
filter(lambda x: '2015-09-01' < x[1], the_list)
```

Which gives:

```
[(3451, '2015-09-01 15:21:15', 4984), 
 (4561, '2015-09-01 15:21:15', 6464),  
 (5671, '2015-09-02 15:21:15', 5484)]
```